# Wireshark how do i know if packet is encrypted?

Tags: mysql, networking, ssl, replication, wireshark

I have a mysql replication setup using SSL i have captured some packets being sent to my slave using wireshark and wanted to know how i would identify if this packet is encrypted using SSL?

Thanks.

Comment: properly encrypted data will essentially look like random garbage. if the packets are going to/coming from an ssl-related port (22, 443, etc...) then most likely it IS encrypted.

Comment: @MarcB  Is the encrypted data at the bottom pane of wireshark? I see some random data on the far right side of this pane.

Comment: no idea. never used wireshark. but there should be a "packet body" section somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since MySQL will use a port that's not necessarily assumed to be using SSL by default (like 443 would be for HTTPS, for example), you need to tell Wireshark to try to decode that traffic as SSL first. You can do this by selecting a packet in that TCP connection and using *right click* -> *Decode As...* -> *Transport* -> *SSL*.

If you can see the handshake messages such as `Client Hello`, `Server Hello` and `Finished`, all this followed by `Application Data`, this is a good indication that SSL/TLS is in use for that connection.

Whether SSL/TLS is used correctly is another matter. You should make sure that your client is configured to verify the server certificate and that it matches the intended host name.

Comment: Thanks i can see all the data has been encrypted, with protocol TLSv1, but there is one thing weird that came up i have captured packets where my master-slave used a unencrypted connection the packets displayed the information being passed even though the protocol was SSL why do think was?

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking. Were you expecting that connection to be encrypted or not?

Comment: I didn't expected it to be encrypted, but i assumed it would only show the protocol as ssl if it was encrypted.